# Monitor for an event without it repeating using Sprite Kit

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit

I know this must be an easy question for someone with experience, but I can't wrap my head around it. I'm working on something in sprite kit and I want to monitor for an even and change a sprite's texture to an animation when it happens.

The event is when the player reaches a specific Y position. I understand how to change it, and the code to watch for it. The issue is the only place I understand to constantly look for the occurrence is in the update loop.

This is what I have in the update loop.

```
if (thePlayer.position.y >= -216){

            //be specific sprite

        } else {

            //be specific animation
}
```

Once the player reachers the < -216 point the animation does trigger, but never leaves frame 1 because its always looping back to start.

Using the update loop has worked for me up till this point because the player sprite has been a static image.

My thought has been to call a function when it reaches that point, but again keep calling that function and never leaving the first frame of the animation.

Again I think I'm missing something pretty easier here, but any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would need to add a Bool to keep track if you're currently running an animation.

Add as a property to your class

```
var runningAnimation = false
```

Then change your condition to use the Bool

```
if (thePlayer.position.y >= -216) {
    runningAnimation = false
    //be specific sprite
} else if (!runningAnimation) {
    runningAnimation = true
    //be specific animation
}
```

Comment: Worked like a charm. I tried something like that, but I guess I missed it. Thanks so much for the help.